# D3js v3 to v4 migraiton merge

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having some problem when i try to migrate my d3js graphs from version 3 to version 4. I have solved a lot o issue, but i'm not understandig how "merge" working. In this code data-title attribute is not setted in V4 and contextmenu is not working.
What's the problem? I don't understand how merge is working. Can someone explain me how to fix this code and why i have to fix it in this way since i have more graphs to fix.

```
    var slice = self.svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(new_node_data), key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .attr("class", "slice").attr("fill", function(d2) { return color(d2.data.name);} )
        .merge(slice) //<-- merge back in update selection
        .transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", tweenIn);

    slice.attr('data-title',function(d){
        return d.data.period + ' ' + d.data.name;
    })

    slice.on("contextmenu", function(d,i){
        console.log(d.data);
        self.context_menu(d.data, i, false);
    });
    self.attach_graph_items_click_event_handler(slice, false, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something simple, after your merge you don't save the combined `update` + `enter` back to a variable (you are missing the `slice =`):

```
slice = slice.enter() //<-- SAVE IT TO A VARIABLE
  .insert("path")
  .attr("class", "slice").attr("fill", function(d2) { return color(d2.data.name);} )
  .merge(slice)
  ....
```

Here's it broken down with comments:

```
// this is your update selection
// slice is a selection of all the things being updated
// in your collection path.slice
var slice = self.svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(new_node_data), key);

// .enter returns the enter selection
// all the things that are being added
slice = slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .attr("class", "slice").attr("fill", function(d2) { return color(d2.data.name);} )
  // this merges the update slice with the enter slice
  .merge(slice)
  // this is now operating on enter + update
  .transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", tweenIn);
```